# MySQL error in Bash

Tags: mysql, bash

i'm trying to load some tables to mysql into a bash script so i have the followin code

```
DOMY="$MYSQL --user=xxxxx --password=xxxxx --database=$DBNAME"

for filename in $(cat $HPATH/toload.tables)
do

    $DOMY < $filename 2>/dev/null

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "#003|Error loading $filename"
        exit 1
    fi

done
```

if i see $? (echo $?) it give me 0 (zero) but the exit 1 is executed.

What i'm doin wrong?

Comment: Why not get rid of the error silencing and find out?

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (putting commands in variables fails). Where are you putting `echo $?`? If another command, such as the `if`, is executed then `$?` holds the exit value of *that* command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't see what's wrong because you have /dev/null-ed standard error.

Also, you are using an unnecessarily complex and somewhat error-prone code pattern where you examine `$?` later. It would be better to just write something like:

```
for i in "$@"; do
  if mysql -u root < $i; then
    echo ok # do "ok" processing here
  else
    echo not so ok # error path
  fi
done
```